# git rm -rf --cached causes remove db. &merge conflict git

Tags: django, git, ubuntu, sqlite

What I want to do is I do not want the locally changed db to be applied to the server and I use Github to handle files.

I wrote db.sqlite3 in '.gitignore' file. But it doesn't work. So I did `git rm -rf —cached .`  and git add, commit, push. The problem is that, in spite of there's DB.sqlite3 file in my local, it causes to remove the db.sqlite3 in GitHub.

How can I apply db.sqlite3 gitignore without git rm -rf --cached. ?

---

When I git pull in ubuntu(AWS, ubuntu instance). The error happens below.

```
your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
health/db.sqlite3
health/nohup
```

So, I did `sudo git stash`
And, when I git pull, `Automatic merge failed: fix conflicts and then commit the result`

git status

```
unmerged paths:
     deleted by them : db.sqlite3
     both modifiled : management/__pacache__/forms.cpython-35.pyc
```

Because, in git there's no db.sqlite3. But I want to store my db in ubuntu server.

How I solve the problem??

Comment: You really shouldn't, but type `git add db.sqlite3`

Comment: @CoryMadden Then why suggest it?  Typically we don't version our database in Git, for the reason that it probably is a large binary file, and could cause the repo to bloat.

Comment: Backup your database using some other method.

Comment: I didn't suggest it. I'm just telling OP how to do what they want. It would be rude for me not to provide information when I'm capable, even if it's not...good information... Though I guess it was rude of me not to provide a reason why they shouldn't.

Comment: Can I use 'upload files' to upload db.sqlite in GitHub page?? I think 'upload db flies using button' or `git add db.sqlite3` is the same result. 
 Isn't it? But, When I wrote the `git add db.sqlite3.` the error happens  `the following paths are ignored by your .gitignore files: health/db.sqlite3  Use -f if you really want to add them`.   I'm a newbie of git.. thank you for your any advice.